# Impact of spurious regressors on out of sample prediction error

Tags: regression, linear-model

The true DGP is 
\begin{equation}
y=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_1 + \dots + \alpha_k x_k +\epsilon, \quad \epsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
but we instead estimate

\begin{equation}
y=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_1 + \dots + \alpha_k x_k + \dots + \alpha_{k'} x_{k'} \epsilon, \quad \epsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)\label{eq:2}
\end{equation}
where $k'>k$. The observations are fixed design.

Is it true that the standard error of the out of sample prediction of the estimated function (with spurious regressors) at some fixed $(x_1^*, \dots, x_{k'}^*)$ is (weakly) greater than the standard error of the out of sample prediction at $(x_1^*, \dots, x_k^*)$ using the correctly specified model? If so, how can I prove this?

Comment: Probably this qualifies as `self-study`. If so, check out the [guidelines](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for this type of questions and edit the post to include the [tag:self-study] tag.